# Who flag the first time posts?

Tags: support, review

I am wondering, Who and how does First-time Posts get flagged? Sometimes I notice that a post appears in the review section within 3 to 5 min. But sometimes it appears after 15 to 30 Mins.

Just for information, how does this work? Is it a system generated flag or does a moderator flag it?

Answer (score 3):

It is a system generated flag. It is nothing that we moderators have control over :)

Probably it runs in batches or as a scheduled tasks, and therefore the time before the flag appears varies (this is just a guess though)